# Why doesn't jr instruction (MIPS) do what I expect it to do in my code?

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions, machine-code

So this is my assembly code for MIPS:

```
#         Assembly                    Description                      Address
main:         addi $2, $0, 5            # intialize $2 = 5             00       
              addi $3, $0, 12           # intialize $3 = 12            04       
              addi $7, $3, -9           # intialize $7 = 3             08       
              addi $8, $0, 44           # should init $8 = 44          0c      
              or   $4, $7, $2           # $4 = (3 OR 5) = 7            10       
              and  $5, $3, $4           # $5 = (12 AND 7) = 4          14       
              add  $5, $5, $4           # $5 = 4 + 7 = 11              18       
              beq  $5, $7, end          # shouldn’t be taken           1c       
              slt $4, $3, $4            # $4 = 12 < 7 = 0              20       
              beq $4, $0, around        # shouldn’t be taken           24       
              addi $5, $0, 0            # shouldn’t be taken           28       
around:       slt $4, $7, $2            # $4 = 3 < 5 = 1               2c       
              add $7, $4, $5            # $7 = 1 + 11 = 12             30       
              sub $7, $7, $2            # $7 = 12 – 5 = 7              34       
              srl $7, $7, 2             # $7 = 7>>2 = 1                38       
              jr $8                     # jump to [8] = 44             3c       
              addi $2, $0, 1            # shouldn’t be taken           40       
              sw $7, 68($3)             # [80] = 1                     44       
              lw $2, 80($0)             # $2 = [80] = 1                48       
              j end                     # should be taken              4c       
              addi $2, $0, 1            # shouldn’t happen             50       
end:          sw $2, 84($0)             # write mem[84] = 1            54
```

It worked fine until I added the jr $8 and addi $2,$0,1 instructions, so the ones at address 3c and 40. I can't tell why it causes the program to fail. I thought that the jr instruction will go to the address inside $8 register, which i specified to be 44 at the 4th instruction, where I initialize $8. The idea was that the jr instruction will made it jumpt to address 44, where then sw instruction will execute, so the addi instruction directly after jr will be omitted.

Why doesn't it do what I want it to do? I run it in MIPS mars and it doesn't seem to ever get to instruction sw when going step by step... Instead, it goes to register number 14...?

Could someone explain what I misunderstood about the jr instruction?

Comment: Make sure the actual load address is zero as that is usually not the case. Just use a label instead of hardcoding the `44`. A little googling indicates the base address is usually `0x400000`.

Comment: @Jester Is there a way to use a label while still using jr instruction? I think I get what it might be. It shows that the address is actually 00400044 at that sw instruction in MIPS. But then doesn't that mean that I can't use addi at all since its limited to 16 bits? I am expected to work with only the instructions visible, but also need a jr instruction in there..

Comment: Are you really only allowed those instructions? Not even a `SLL`? Anyway, then you can first load `0x4000` then simulate `SLL` using a couple of `ADD` instructions to get `0x400000` before adding the `0x44`.

Comment: @Jester okay though that might be the solution. I'll try that now.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you sure? I think that goes to whatever absolute address is in register `$8`. It's not a relative jump adding `8` to the PC. `JR` is _"jump register"_.

Comment: @Jester Thanks for your help, I have done addi, then many adds, and finally addi the reminder of what I needed and have tested it to see that it works!

Comment: "the addi instruction directly after jr will be omitted." The addi will execute because it sits in the branch delay slot.

Answer (score 0):

Hi leaving an answer as I can't comment yet. Looks like you found one solution. Not sure if you can add variables from memory in this particular exercise but yes, immediate data are restricted to 16 bits. What I usually do is to declare a variable in .data such as 0x100000 to represent the address and then load it into a register to access that mem address. I tend to use it as displacement but I don't see why it shouldn't work as a solution to your issue too.